# Changing the position of one flex child without having to manually assign the "order" property to others

Tags: css, flexbox

I was interested swapping the order of my first flex child with the second. The problem I have is that I could potentially be dealing with a dozen or more divs. Is there a way I can assign the order of **one** flex child without having to assigning the `order` property to each one? Otherwise the first div gets pushed to the bottom.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child:first-of-type {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I was interested swapping the order of my first flex child with the
>   second.

Give the second `order: -1`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
</div>
```

> Is there a way I can assign the order of one flex child without having
>   to assigning the order property to each one

No, if you want to move one between two other, you can't do that with just 1 rule, you need 2

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child:nth-child(n+8) {
  order: 2;
}
.child:nth-child(5) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change all of them to order 2, and only the second to order 1:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.child:nth-child(2) {
  order: 1;
}

.child {
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Default value for order property is 0. Not depends of position in HTML code, all elements have 0 order unless you specify other. So, by swap order between first and second elements, enough with:

```
div:nth-child(2) {
  order: -1;
}
```